# React Native focus issue when having two TextInput elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two `InputField` components that I have created using `TextInput`:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
>
  <View>
    <InputField
      value={value1}
      onChangeText={onVal1Change}
    />
    <InputField
      value={value2}
      onChangeText={onVal2Change}
    />
  </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

And this is the code for the `InputField` component:

```
const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState<boolean>(false);
const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);

const onPress = () => {
  setIsFocus(true);
  if (inputRef.current) {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }
}

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
  <View>
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      ref={inputRef}
      onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
      onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
    />
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

The issue is when pressing on one `InputField`, it's focusing on the input but the cursor stays on the previous focused `InputField`. I know the `.focus()` function is working using `console.log` on the `current` focused input but the cursor itself does not move to the pressed element (meaning the keyboard does not appear on the correct input context).

What seems to be the issue in my code? or in general?

**NOTE:** that I'm using this component for additional styling and animation.

Comment: adding a key to InputField might solve this

Comment: @Abd without using this `key` prop inside `InputField`? it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your code on codesandbox [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68872292-fzglc?file=/src/App.tsx). It seems there isn't a problem with your code itself.

For one thing, I think you can remove "isFocus" variable since you're not using it. (OR remove the inputRef and just use the isFocus variable, which I think is better).